# Vuetify - password input - append-icon - tab from text field to icon to text field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying example located on Vuetify's website. Located here

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#password-input

When you try to tab from text field to text field you focus on the mdi-eye or mdi-eye-off icon. Is there a way to prevent this behavior. I would like user to be able to tab from text field to text field. Rather than text field to icon to text field.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the Vuetify append-icon from the sequential keyboard navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362420/how-to-remove-the-vuetify-append-icon-from-the-sequential-keyboard-navigation)