# How to remove the Vuetify append-icon from the sequential keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

In a Vue.js app with Vuetify, I have a set of password fields defined with a `v-text-field` and which have an `append-icon` in order to switch the text visibility, as follows:

```
      <v-text-field
        v-model="password"
        :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
        :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
        @click:append="show1 = !show1"
      ></v-text-field>
```

It is exactly similar to the [documentation example for password input](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#password-input) (See also the corresponding [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-fields%2F)).

With this set-up, if a user uses the `Tab` key to navigate across the different fields (sequential keyboard navigation), the `append-icon`s are included in the sequential keyboard navigation.

I would like to exclude these icons from this sequential keyboard navigation (and be able to jump from one password field to the other without navigating to the `append-icon`).

Standard way to do that is to assign a "negative value (usually `tabindex="-1"`)" which "means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation", as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

But I don't find how to assign a `tab-index` value only to the `append-icon` and not to the `v-text-field` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `v-slot:append` and place the icon there.

```
<v-text-field v-model="password" :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'">
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-button @click="show1 = !show1" tabindex="-1">
      <v-icon v-if="show1" >mdi-eye</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-if="show1" >mdi-eye-off</v-icon>
    </v-button>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

However, it's not because you can do this that you should.
If you place this button outside of reach of tabindex, someone with a screenreader might not be able to toggle the button.
From an accesibility concern, this button is an interactive element and thus should have `tabindex="0"`

Answer (score 4):

What also worked for me is to just assign the tabindex for all elements. The *append-icon* will be ignored then.

```
<v-text-field 
  tabindex="1" 
  v-model="password" 
  :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'" 
  :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'" 
  @click:append="show1 = !show1">
</v-text-field>
<v-btn tabindex="2" @click="submitForm">Submit</v-btn>
```

Comment: this is the simpler solution rather than modifying v-slot and it is a fairly faster and easier quick-fix